# Create a dictionary of Widgets using elements of a list as keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am creating a GUI and I want to access some of my widgets. Since they are many I want to call all of them and put in a dictionary. I already have on dictionary `dicA` and I want to use the the same keys, but with some restrictions:

```
for row_nr in range(0,8):
    for cln_nr in range(0,8):
        self.current_Frame = self.gridLayout_10.itemAtPosition(row_nr, cln_nr)
        self.dicA[row_nr+1, cln_nr+1] = self.current_Frame


for keys in sorted(self.dicA.keys()):
    if keys[0] == 1 or keys[0] == 8  or keys[1] == 1 or keys[1] == 8:
        for info_nr in range(1, 29):
            self.info_names = 'info_'+str(info_nr)
            self.current_entry = self.Matrix.findChild(QtGui.QTextEdit, self.info_names)
            self.dicB[keys] = self.current_entry
```

In the end what I wanted is to have a dictionary which contains as keys the same keys as `dicA`, but following those restrictions, and associated with that each widget found by `self.current_entry`.

But when I run this code, I get the keys, as I wished, however it associates he last widget `info_28` to all the keys.

The first dictionary works just as I wanted, but the second no, what am I missing?

Comment: Change `self.current_Frame` to `current_Frame` and `self.current_entry` to `current_entry`

Comment: I still get the same result, just the last widget is added to all the keys

Comment: What is the point of that inner loop? You are assigning every widget (1, 29) to the same `keys`. And why are you using `findChild`? Why not just `self.dicB[keys] = self.dicA[keys]`?

Comment: Because I wanted to assign every children found by this loop to every `keys`, in a sorted way.  The `self.gridLayout_10.itemAtPosition(row_nr, cln_nr)` does not give me information about the item. I cannot call, for example, `.toPlainText()` if I find them like that, right?

Answer (score 0):

after assigning keys to dictionary check if key is present in dictionary than skip else add that key to dict

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it in a better way. The first `dicA` had as keys the positions on the grid. So I made the following

```
    for info_nr in range(1, 29):
                self.info_names = 'info_'+str(info_nr)
                self.current_entry = self.Matrix.findChild(QtGui.QTextEdit, self.info_names)
                idx = self.gridLayout_10.indexOf(self.current_entry)                    
                loc = self.gridLayout_10.getItemPosition(idx)
                self.dicB[loc[0], loc[1]] = self.current_entry
```